# How to solve $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am stuck with this equation. All I could do is this:
$\lfloor x \rfloor$ = $\lfloor n + m \rfloor$ such that $n \in N$ and $m<1$.
We get:

$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 1$

$\lfloor n + m \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{1}{n+m} \rfloor = 1$

$n + \lfloor m \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{1}{n+m} \rfloor = 1$

$n + 0 + \lfloor \frac{1}{n+m} \rfloor = 1$

$n + \lfloor \frac{1}{n+m} \rfloor = 1$

From here on I have no idea what to do!

Edit: It is easy to see that any value $1<x<2$ satisfies the equation, but can I find all the solutions?

Comment: Well, have you found *some* solutions at least?

Comment: Split the problem. For ex., on $[0,1]$, $\lfloor x \rfloor = 0$ so you are left with the second term only. Also, for which values of $y$, $\lfloor y \rfloor = 1$ holds ?

Comment: For a start : What is $\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor $ for $x>1$ ? Next consider that $0<x<1$ can be transformed into the case $x>1$. The negative case is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes, values such as 3/2 do satisfy the equation. It is quite obvious that any value $1<x<2$ satisfies the equation, but how can I find all the solutions?

Comment: If $x≥2$ can $x$ be a solution?  What if $0<x≤.5$?

Comment: With $x$ , $\frac{1}{x}$ is a solution as well.

Comment: Oh, yes of course, now I see it. Since values greater than 2 cannot satisfy the equation and values less than 0.5 cannot either (and it is fairly easy to prove this), it follows that the only positive numbers that satisfy this equation are $\frac{1}{2} < x < 2$

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh Actually, there is one $x$ in that range that does **not** satisfy the equation.

Comment: Yes, 1 itself does not.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to solve $\lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor =c$ you can consider the pairs of values that $a$ and $b$ can take.

In this case your possibilities are very small: $a=0, b=1$ or $a=1, b=0$.

Can you proceed from there?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

1. For $x>0$ and $x\neq 1$, one of the two values, $x$ or $\frac1x$, is between $0$ and $1$, so the floor of that value will be $0$.
2. If $x$ is a solution, then so is $\frac1x$. This means you can first only focus on $x>1$, to get half of the solutions, then know that this is just half of the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can notice that for $
x>1,$ $\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor=0$

Then x solution and $ x>1$  if and only if $ x$ strictly between 1 and 2

for $0<x<1 : \lfloor x \rfloor=0$ , then $x$ solution if and only if $\lfloor\frac{1}{x} \rfloor=1$ which can easily be solved using the definition of the floor function , then
$x$ solution if and only if  $x$ strictly between $0.5 $ and $1$

Clearly if $x$ negative x is not a solution .

Answer (score 0):

We can rule out $x<0$. If $x\geqslant 2$, then $1-\lfloor x \rfloor \leqslant -1$, which is problematic. If $x\leqslant 1/2$, then $\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 1-\lfloor x \rfloor$ is again impossible. For any $x\in (1/2, 2)\setminus \{1\}$ we have
$$ \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor =1. $$